# can't I dispatch actions in sequence?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to display a loading spinner im my react app when a user is clicking on 'save'.
I'd like to dispatch an action that will update my redux store as loading to true and as false when the api call is finished.
The thing is i'm currently using middleware that handles all the code related to api calls. Whenever this code is running, is seems to always be 'false', maybe because the dispatch actions are batched ?

So should I have this dispatch loading action in the middleware or not necessarily ?

Thanks !

```
    const handleSave = () => {
        dispatch(isLoading(true))
        dispatch(updateProfileImage());
        dispatch(isLoading(false))
    };
```

Comment: By chance, have you ever come across [this one](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic)?

Comment: Why don't you wrap your `dispatch(isLoading())` calls in your  `updateProfileImage` where you use thunk or saga middleware to call an API?  Just before the API call make `dispatch(isLoading(true)) and in the finally block if you have a try catch for API call,  `dispatch(isLoading(false))`

Comment: I was thinking about it, but I was not sure it was the proper way to handle the loading part. Thanks for your suggestions :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use thunk, you can combine thunks in thunks and wait for thunks **if it returns a promise**, here is a pseudo example:

```
const doThisThunk = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loadingThis(true));
  //returning a promise here
  return (
    asyncStuff()
      .then(
        (resolve) => dispatch(updateThis(resolve)),
        (error) => dispatch(errorThis(error))
      )
      //no matter resolve or reject, set loading false
      //https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/finally
      .finally(() => dispatch(loadingThis(false)))
  );
};
const doThatThunk = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(loadingThat(true));
  //returning a promise here
  return (
    asyncStuff()
      .then(
        (resolve) => dispatch(updateThat(resolve)),
        (error) => dispatch(errorThat(error))
      )
      .finally(() => dispatch(loadingThat(false)))
  );
};
const doThisThenDoThatThunk = () => (dispatch) =>
  //bodiless function automatically returns return value
  //  of the next line
  dispatch(doThisThunk()).then(() => dispatch(doThatThunk()));
```

The above example also shows how you set loading logic in your thunk.

Comment: actually Sanish Joseph's answer is what I was thinking about. in my 'api' middleware I just dispatched the loading to true or false in my try block and in my finally block. Thanks for the help